# text selection using greedy and reluctant

Tags: python, regex, text, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract text between markers. But these markers are word tokens and repeat frequently. input is EDGAR txt files. 
My markers are ITEM some number ie. ITEM 1 and ITEM2.

my regex is

```
MDA_regex = 'item[^a-zA-Z\n]*\d\s*\.\s*management\'s discussion and analysis.*?item[^a-zA-Z\n]*\d\s*'
```

It is working fine but it fails if keyword item\d... occur between ITEM 1 AND ITEM 2. If i use .* it goes to other unwanted marker as the reports may contains other item\d.... If use .*? it will stuck at first occurance of item.

I cannot hardcode 1 and 2 because different reports can have different position/header ie. item 7 to item 8 for my required text. I am using python

```
for fileName in os.listdir(path):
    fileName = os.path.join(path, fileName)
    if os.path.isfile(fileName):
        print("opening new file " + fileName)
        with open(fileName, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as in_file:
            content = in_file.read().replace('\n',' ')
            mda_list=re.findall(MDA_regex,content, re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
            print(mda_list)
            print(len(mda_list))
```

My input is like

```
Management's Discussion and Analysis of Financial Condition and
Results of Operations............................................. 22

Item 3. 

ITEM 1 . MANAGEMENT'S DISCUSSION AND ANALYSIS OF FINANCIAL CONDITION
AND RESULTS OF OPERATIONS.

FORWARD-LOOKING STATEMENTS
This report contains forward-looking statements. Additional
written or oral forward-looking statements may be made by AMERCO from
time to time in filings with the Securities and Exchange Commission or
otherwise. Management believes such forward-looking statements are
within the meaning of the safe-harbor provisions. Such item 1 statements may
include, but not be limited to, projections of revenues, income or
<PAGE> 33 
      ITEM 2. QUANTITATIVE AND QUALITATIVE DISCLOSURES ABOUT MARKET RISK
DFDFDLF;DF SDLKD dlfldfkdffd;fl;l sdsl; dklkkdsmm,sd item 4
DDFLDFL dlkdsldkf dldfd;lf;f
```

Also 'item' can not be caps because some reports have caps and some don,t.
Can someone suggest how to handle this. Should i use multiple regex in if-else condition to check each condition.

Comment: Add `^` before the last `item` in the pattern (to only match `item` at the line start) and use `re.M` flag, too. See https://regex101.com/r/5S9IFY/1. However, you should not replace newlines with a space. Remove `.replace('\n',' ')`, or use it after applying the regex.

Comment: I tried your solution but it showing 0 result. The thing is Item 2 can from start of line as well as with some blanksapces in front.

Comment: Adding `\s*` after `^` is not a rocket science. https://regex101.com/r/5S9IFY/4